# C/C++ function as parameter

Tags: c++

```
bool isContainedSameForm(AG ag1, AG ag2){
    if(isEmpty(ag2)) return false; 
    return isContainedSameForm(ag1->pH,ag2->pH) && isContainedSameForm(ag1->sH,ag2->sH);
};
int sameFormOcurrences(AG ag1,AG ag2,bool (*isContainedSameForm)(AG,AG)){
    if(isEmpty(ag2)) return 0;
    int ret=0;
    if(isContainedSameForm(ag1,ag2)) ret=1;
    return ret + sameFormOcurrences(ag1,ag2->pH,isContainedSameForm) + sameFormOcurrences(ag1,ag2->sH,isContainedSameForm);
};

int sameFormOcurrences( AG ag1, AG ag2){
    return sameFormOcurrences(ag1,ag2,isContainedSameForm);
}
```

AG being a general tree, this counts how many times a tree of the same form appears in the second tree

[image]

What I don't understand is the purpose of the first **sameFormOcurrences** function receiving a **isContainedSameForm** in parameters.

Is is just a way to change the signature without changing the name of it? 
Isn't it redundant with the function being declared above already if it's trying to avoid a non defined method?

Comment: Yeah, what purpose does it serve in this case?

Comment: It's a predicate. It means you could pass a different algorithm for checking if it's contained in the same form without changing sameFormOcurrences.

Comment: It lets you use your own function instead of hardcoded to `isContainedSameForm` as it would be with a normal function call. The fact the parameter has the same name is inconsequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't written in the best style, the function pointer parameter, and the function implementing that, really should have different names.  Right now if there were a typo in the parameter declaration, the code inside the function would refer directly to another function, and the parameter would silently become useless.

This would be much better:

```
int countMatchingDescendants(AG ag1,AG ag2,bool (*matchCondition)(AG,AG))
{
    if(isEmpty(ag2)) return 0;
    int ret=0;
    if(matchCondition(ag1,ag2)) ret=1;
    return ret + countMatchingDescendants(ag1,ag2->pH,matchCondition) + countMatchingDescendants(ag1,ag2->sH,matchCondition);
}

bool isContainedSameForm(AG ag1, AG ag2)
{
    if(isEmpty(ag2)) return false; 
    return isContainedSameForm(ag1->pH,ag2->pH) && isContainedSameForm(ag1->sH,ag2->sH);
}

int sameFormOcurrences( AG ag1, AG ag2)
{
    return countMatchingDescendants(ag1,ag2,isContainedSameForm);
}
```

Note that I've only changed identifier names, not the structure of the code (I also removed extraneous semicolons outside the function bodies).  But now the counting code has a generic name indicating how flexible it actually is.

By changing the order, I prevent any possibility of the generic counting code accidentally referring to a concrete implementation.

Comment: How is that an answer to the question?